# React app with express backend having problem with CORS. (I am using docker)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, cors

I have been facing a really awkward problem with docker with CORS.
Same code is working flawlessly on the local machine.
I am using npm package cors.
My backend is running on pert 3000 and frontend is running on 4000.
Here is the code in my app.ts file.

```
this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
      
        // TODO Add origin validation
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Cache-Control, Pragma');
      
        // intercept OPTIONS method
        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
          res.sendStatus(204);
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    this.app.options('*', cors());
```

And here is the code of my config file

```
allowedDomains: ["http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:4000"]
```

I have also added the proxy in package.json file

```
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3000/api"
```

here is the error in the browser console

**Edit**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/lighting/lighting. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

**Edit 2**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

This is coming in response headers when I am making request to api only i.e on 3000 port but this is not coming in when I am making the request to frontend.

but still no luck.
I have been stuck on this issue for over 2 days.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: _still no luck_. What does that mean? Are you facing an error? On the client side or on the server side? If so, what is the error message? Edit your question and add more details.